# OpenCV compiles correctly but fails during .deb packaging

Tags: 18.04, package-management, deb, cmake, opencv

Attempting to follow some tutorials on building a .deb package for a newer version of OpenCV in Ubuntu 18.04.  Here are my steps:

```
wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.1.0.zip
unzip 4.1.0.zip
cd opencv-4.1.0
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DOPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

At this point I edit the CMakeCache.txt file, and modify this line from `OFF` to `ON`:

```
CPACK_BINARY_DEB:BOOL=ON
```

This next step compiles everything successfully, but then fails during the creation of the .deb package:

```
make -j4 package
```

This is the tail end of the output it produces with the error messages:

```
Run CPack packaging tool...
CPack: Create package using DEB
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: OpenCV
CPack: - Install project: OpenCV
CPack: -   Install component: dev
CPack: -   Install component: java
CPack: -   Install component: libs
CPack: -   Install component: licenses
CPack: -   Install component: python
CPack: -   Install component: scripts
CPack: Create package
CPackDeb: - Generating dependency list
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CPackDeb.cmake:709 (message):
  CPackDeb: dpkg-shlibdeps: '
  dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libopencv_calib3d.so.4.1 needed by ./usr/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/usr/local/lib')
  dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libopencv_features2d.so.4.1 needed by ./usr/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/usr/local/lib')
  dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libopencv_highgui.so.4.1 needed by ./usr/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/usr/local/lib')
  dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libopencv_videoio.so.4.1 needed by ./usr/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/usr/local/lib')
  dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libopencv_imgproc.so.4.1 needed by ./usr/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/usr/local/lib')
  dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libopencv_core.so.4.1 needed by ./usr/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/usr/local/lib')
...cut lots more...
  dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot continue due to the errors listed above
  Note: libraries are not searched in other binary packages that do not have any shlibs or symbols file.
  To help dpkg-shlibdeps find private libraries, you might need to use -l.
  ';
  executed command: '/usr/bin/dpkg-shlibdeps --ignore-missing-info -O ./usr/bin/opencv_annotation;./usr/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration;./usr/bin/opencv_version;./usr/bin/opencv_visualisation';
```

Can anyone shed light on what I must do to create the OpenCV .deb file?

Answer (score 4):

A little late in answering, but I landed here because I was looking for answers to the same problem on nVidia Jetson Nano. Eventually, I dug a little bit to solve it. Here is what I did to successfully build a `.deb` package.

After "cmake"ing and turning the flag `CPACK_BINARY_DEB:BOOL` on,

1. `make` first.
2. Edit the `CPackConfig.cmake` file in your build directory

   1. to **comment out** the line `set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS "TRUE")` -- borrowed from [this Mozilla Services lua_sandbox](https://github.com/mozilla-services/lua_sandbox/issues/175) resolved issue.
   2. to replace all occurrences of `unknown` (version) to `4.1.0`.
3. Edit the `CPackSourceConfig.cmake` to replace all occurrences of `unknown` (version) to `4.1.0`.
4. `make package`

Step 1 allows the package tool to find the missing library dependencies that need to be built first. The first edit in step 2 allowed building the deb package, and other edits allowed building packages with numeric version number (correct thing to do for future upgrades), without which `dpkg` complains.

Comment: I have this problem, but I get ```broken symbolic link to``` messages

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `make install` before calling `make package`.

Answer (score 0):

Best information I got was from the opencv documentation [tutorial linux install](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) and [tutorial config reference](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html)

I ended up using these steps to build a .deb package:

```
# Install basic tools
sudo apt install -y g++
sudo apt install -y cmake
sudo apt install -y make
sudo apt install -y git

# Clone repo and make build folder
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout 4.x
mkdir -p build && cd build

# create files from cmake
cmake .. \
 -DCPACK_BINARY_DEB=ON \
 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
make -j$(nproc)

# Install files before building .deb package
sudo make install
cpack -G DEB
sudo make uninstall
```